Can we make 300 ohm 300 watt resistor from three 100 ohm 100 watt resistors?
We have three 100-ohm, 100-watt resistors, but we need a 300-ohm, 300-watt resistor. Can we create a combination to achieve this? We aim to dissipate 150 watts through the circuit. If I connect three 100-ohm resistors in series, will the resistor be damaged?

What's the tolerance on them?


Can we create a combination to achieve this?


Three 100 Ω resistors in series gives you 300 Ω
The total power handling will be 3 x 100 watts = 300 watts
But, make sure they are sufficiently thermally isolated from each other
Use resistors with the same temperature coefficient


If I connect three 100-ohm resistors in series, will the resistor be
damaged?

There should be no damage but make sure you follow the guidance in the data sheet for the resistors in terms of any heatsinking requirements and consider power derating if ambient temperature around the resistors gets too high.

"make sure they are sufficiently thermally isolated from each other" Why? Shouldn't it be even somewhat advantageous to couple them thermally to make sure all have a similar temperature?

@jusaca some semiconductor devices benefit from thermal matching. Resistors dissipating a lot of power need to each have their own path to a heatsink. If they are close enough to each other to heat each other up, this means their cooling is compromised, and they will get hotter than they should.

If you are putting 150W into this it will be fine.
The problem with putting 300W onto the resistors in series is that the power dissipated in each resistor will vary slightly. When resistors are manufactured they are not all exactly the same value. They can vary by an amount which is expressed as a percentage and referred to as tolerance.
It depends on the resistor type but for power resistors can be as high as 10%. You need to make an allowance for this when calculating the maximum safe power you can out onto the resistors.
Differences in heatsinking and other thermal environment variables will probably make at least as much difference as this.

An old school rule of thumb is derate a resistor by 50% (meaning if it will dissipate a half watt continuously in your circuit, use a 1 watt resistor).  However, that rule was used for low wattage resistors.  For 300 watts, for sure you need to spend some time defining the level of safety factor your system needs, including the manufacturer's data sheet info on heat dissipation (and tolerances as stated above).

The short answer is yes, that's fine.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A single 300W, 300Ω resistor R1 can have up to 300V across it. In that condition, power in R1 is:
$$ P_1 = \frac{V^2}{R_1} = \frac{(300V)^2}{300\Omega} = 300W $$
The three resistors R2, R3 and R4 in series have a total resistance of 300Ω, and with 300V across them they will each pass the same current, as shown on ammeter AM1:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R_2+R_3+R_4} = \frac{300V}{300\Omega} = 1A $$
Each resistor, having the same resistance of 100Ω and passing the same 1A of current, will therefore develop the same voltage, as shown on the volmeters:
$$ V_2 = I \times R_2 = 1A \times 100\Omega = 100V $$
$$ V_3 = I \times R_3 = 1A \times 100\Omega = 100V $$
$$ V_4 = I \times R_4 = 1A \times 100\Omega = 100V $$
Knowing both the current through each resistor, and the voltage across each resistor, you have two ways to calculate power in each resistor:
$$ P = I^2R = (1A)^2 \times 100\Omega = 100W $$
$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{(100V)^2}{100\Omega} = 100W $$
Either approach should yield the same result, 100W.
All three resistors, then, will together dissipate a total of 300W, shared equally between them. Each individual resistor will dissipate only 100W, which it is rated to withstand, so you're good from a specification perspective.
You still must ensure that those resistors are able to dispense with that heat, so don't bunch them together. Make sure that there's adequate air-flow around them each individually.
